# How do I stop Windows from flooding smartcard with APDUs

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, smartcard

Whenever I put a smartcard in/on my smartcard reader Windows (7 Prof, x64) immediately starts flooding it with APDUs possibly trying to identify the type of the card (SELECT and READ_DATA commands).

How do I turn off this behavior?
I'm a smartcard developer and these APDUs ruin my test setup.

Comment: This happens with multiple readers or just one specific one?

Comment: I checked with two readers - didn't check APDUs in details but ammount and kind appear the same. Concerning the second reader I'm absolutely sure I never explicitly installed any driver or bundle software.

Comment: To be exact I can not rule out that the readers are responsible for sending the APDUs. I tried to power them just by power supply not connected to any host computer. I did not receive any APDUs from both readers then. However one reader has a status led which was not powered compared to being connected to a host computer

Comment: Did you try disabling Smart Card Plug & Play?

Comment: Yes, set it to disabled via gpedit, rebooted and did not notice any difference